# Creating case class structure from a Json example file

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, spray, case-class

I've a JSON representation (for a Web Service). The JSON has quite a large number of fields. I want to deserialize(serialize) Json to a case class (case to Json) so that I can use it inside Spray/Play framework.

Before I start writing my case classes I was wondering if there is something that allows the creation a set of case classes from an example Json. Something similar to how you can create Java classes for an XML/SOAP schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone has made this useful application http://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io.

[Link to Github repo](https://github.com/CleverCloud/json2caseclass)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thxs.

Comment: Answers like this are a lot more useful with some extra context. A full project name, another link or two (to the GitHub repo, for example), and a couple of sentences about the approach used would make this answer not useless if / when the link above goes dead.